# How can I add some text to the url only if a user is logged in?

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

I need the url to have something like www.example.com/logged-in/rest-of-url . I can't seem to find much about changing the url other that when I add a new page or if I want to do an alias. Does anyone have any experience doing something like this.

Comment: Can you give some more details as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish by changing the URL for logged in users? In Drupal, the URL is an argument that is passed to a PHP function, which retrieves the appropriate content for the requested page. You can't really change that argument and retrieve the same content unless you create an alias.

Comment: I'm getting a zero charge rating from my ISP for my site for when users are logged in so all the urls for logged in users needs to be different.

Comment: How is your ISP going to track that? You could just alias every single page to a "logged in" URL that would  be accessible whether or not the user is logged in.

Comment: I honestly don't know nor do I even care. I was just asked to do this so any answer would be helpful.

Comment: You could create a custom module to create an alias to the content with the new URL and then you would have to alter every link on the site for logged-in users so that it points them to the aliased URL rather than the original (although you could only affect links that are built programmatically, such as menus, but not links inside of content). However, this wouldn't actually prevent access to the "logged in" URLS (or content) by non-logged in users.

Comment: What is a "zero charge rating?"  You could use the UserID in the URL to simplify uniqueness, but your Drupal configuration and modules enabled would heavily dictate if this is possible or reasonable.  Need more information about your setup and your end goals to really go into more detail.